# .eslintignore is not ignoring my directory

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want ESLint to ignore my "views" folder and create an .eslintignore file in the project root directory for that.

Inside, I've added the folder I want to ignore:

`/views`

But it is not working (should some configurations need to be added in package.json?).

I don't want to use `/* eslint-disable */` at the top of the file that needs to be ignored.

Here is how my project structure looks like: 
[image: Project structure]

Comment: If you're using VS Code's built-in ESLint support, Did you try disabling and re-enabling ESLint for the project from the VS Code command palette?

Comment: Have you tried just plain `views` without the leading slash?

Comment: I've tried both variants - none of them worked

Answer (score 7):

Your `.eslintignore` is placed inside `/views`, you need to move it into `/`.